# Weapons are dissapearing when the player has a package on

Tags: animation, lua, roblox

[image]

Basically, if you have a package on, when you equip an item, the script can't find the Motor6D called "RightHandM6D". This is true for the left hand, torso, etc. When you have no packages on, as in the blocky avatar, the script can find the Motor6D called "RightHandM6D".

**Error message:  RightHandM6D is not a valid member of MeshPart "Workspace.Vlo_tz.RightHand"**

Vlo_tz is my in game name.

This is my server script.

```lua
local RightHandM6D = Instance.new("Motor6D", char.RightHand)
RightHandM6D.Name = "RightHandM6D"
```

This is my Local script, and the error relates to this script.

```lua
game.ReplicatedStorage.ConnectM6D:FireServer(WeaponTool.BodyAttach, char.RightHand, char.RightHand.RightHandM6D)
```

Left ones avatar works, right ones avatar doesnt work.